# How do I fix sweet alert so that it shows text on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, scroll, sweetalert

The text and icon of the popup do not show on certain android devices. Here is a [video](http://cl.ly/c9fc) showing what happens.

This does not happen on desktop or iOS.

Here is my code which is in my site head:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  swal({
    title: "How can we help?",
    text: "Do you need to sell your house?",
    type: "info",
    animation: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false },
    function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm) {
        swal({
          title: "We can help!",
          text: "We have all the information you need, ready to see it?",
          type: "success",
          confirmButtonText: "Show me!",
          cancelButtonText: "No thanks"
        },
        function(){
          window.location.href = '/sell-your-house/';
        });
      }
      else {
        swal({
          title: "That's okay!",
          text: "We'll be here when you need us!",
          type: "error",
          confirmButtonText: "Back to Browsing",
        });
      }
  });
}, 5000);
</script>
```

I was using the animation: "slide-from-top" and tried changing to just 'true' but that didn't help. I also tried 'false' and just excluding the line, "animation:".

I think preventing scroll just moments before the popup *might* help but I don't know how to do that either. And it also feels like a hack and not a bona-fide solution...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: You can see this live at http://volhomes.com